# How to ignore timestamp while converting date object to instant type in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using the below function to convert Date to timestamp but it is taking timezone I need only the date with no timezone to Instant type

```
convertDateToTimeStamp(date: any) {
  return Date.parse(date) / 1000;
}
```

Before calling convertDateToTimeStamp()  the date value is **Fri Mar 24 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)****

After calling the convertDateToTimeStamp() the date value is **1490328000** which is **Thursday, November 26, 2015 12:00:00 AM GMT-05:00**

I dont need any GMT , the date should be same across all the timezones

Comment: Are you using TypeScript?  The question seems independent of Angular.  Please edit tags if this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

```
convertDateToTimeStamp(date: any) {
  return new Date(date).toUTCString();
}
```